# ofstream (C++) does not create file (permission denied)

Tags: c++, operating-system, chromium, permission-denied, ofstream

I'm digging an open source project (Chromium) which is written in c++ and I want to create a file and write to it. BTW, I build the source code using Ninja build system. Here is my code to create a file:

```
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("collectedData.txt", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
if (myfile.is_open()){
    std::cout << "file is open.\n";
    myfile << "Hello from Chrome!" ;
    myfile << "\n" ;
}else {
    std::cout << "error -> " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
    std::cout <<"file cannot be opened.\n";
}
myfile.close();
```

So the problem is that I get permission denied error with this code and it does not create the file. However, when I create a new project (using VS2010) and copy .exe file of the project in the same directory of the Chromium, the code creates the file. So I think there is no problem with the directory permission.

In addition, I checked the task manager and found several Chrome.exe processes, so I thought maybe it's because of concurrent processes. Then I decided to check this and added **cin** command to the above code (to the new project in VS2010), before closing the file and run concurrent processes (.exe). In this way, I don't close the file and open several instances of it. Surprisingly, all programs successfully can open the file and write to it.

I do not know what to check more, I was wondering if anyone can help me with this.

**UPDATE:**
I found the problem and you can find the solution in the the answer part.

Comment: If the file already exists and is open by another process you will get permission denied status.  If this is the problem, this question/answer may help: http://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows

Comment: @Dale Wilson: I think at least the code should create the file if the file does not exist.

Comment: Have you verified that the file does not exist?   Try opening a file that you know exists in the directory where you expect your file to be created to verify that your working directory is set correctly.

Comment: @Dale Wilson: Yup, I'm sure about the working directory and also non existence of the file.

Comment: You should take that update and add it as an answer to this question.

Comment: @JA_FKH You absolutely can answer your own question and should so it helps other people. You should edit the **update** part out of your question and format the answer well. Then you should get upvotes from anyone that visits.

Comment: @Ben: thanks for formatting the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the directory permissions nor the compiler issues. The problem is that Chrome has several renderer processes and these processes are sand-boxed (as opposed to the browser process). So, they do not have permission to write a file.

To overcome this problem use `--no-sandbox flag` to give the file access permission to the renderer processes. Build chrome and then run it from console using the following code (for win):

```
chrome.exe --no-sandbox
```

Answer (score 0):

That is really an OS question..
If you're using windows, rightclick the project folder > properties > security, and give it edit, read and write permissions(And apply to all sub files/folders).

Or maybe theres a security problem with your compiler (sounds more likely). I had the exact same problem a couple years ago.. Just find your compilers install directory, and do the same as mentioned about your project folder.

Comment: okay thanks for the feedback, I have to check it and will return the result.